# Automatically Export Build and Release definitions using Powershell or DEVOPS tasks

Tags: azure-devops

Have a requirement to automatically export specific Azure DEVOPS Build/Release definitions. I know the names of the definitions required. The process would run weekly to capture the information. I know the export can be done manually but want to automate process. Hoping Powershell script can be used.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 3):

If you want to export the build/release definition automatically, you'd better use **Powershell** task with **Rest API**. But if this, it is not enough for just know the build definition name.

Refer to these docs: [get build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and [get release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). You can see that **definitionid** is necessary. In fact, this **definitionid** is very easy to get. Just click the relevant pipeline you want to export, the **definitionid** will display in URL:

[image]

To export the definition, you can use the follow script in powershell:

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$projectsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{build definitionid}?api-version=5.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers 
$filename=$result.name+".json"
$filePath="D:\"
$file=$filePath+$filename
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

In this script, I specified the build name as the file name(`$filename=$result.name+".json"`), and also, convert the result content as **JSON** to make the local file more readable:

[image]

Similarly, to get the release definition, just change the url as get release difinition:

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$projectsUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers 
$filename=$result.name+".json"
$filePath="D:\"
$file=$filePath+$filename
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

**Note:** While use `@{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }`, you'd enable `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` to make the environment variable available during build pipeline.

In addition, as what you want is capture the information weekly, you can **Schedule** the pipeline which has these export task:

[image]

Now, these export pipeline will run and export the definition weekly.

Comment: Got it, Will give this a try.  Thank you Merlin Liang

Comment: @J.Cortese Welcome:-) Hope my method can achieve what you want. Hoping your result

Comment: @J.Cortese Hi, how the things going? Does the script can help you achieve what you want? Feel free to let us know the latest status.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking at the `az pipelines release` and `az pipelines build` commands from [Azure DevOps CLI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.cli)

[Commands Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest)

[Extension Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)